# Component ‘RICHTX32.OCX’ or one of its dependencies not correctly registered: a file is missing or invalid

Tags: dependencies, components

I have `RICHTX32.OCX` registered and `MSCOMCT2.OCX` registered as well using a batch file initiated by Computer Group Policy.

```
[RegOcx.cmd]
cd %systemroot%\SysWoW64
copy \\2012fs01\software\ocx\*.* C:\Windows\SysWoW64 /y
%systemroot%\SysWoW64\regsvr32.exe RichTx32.ocx /s
%systemroot%\SysWoW64\regsvr32.exe MSCOMCT2.ocx /s
```

When I test this on the Windows 2012 R2 64 bit server with my own username, which is an admin.The VB6 program runs ok.
When a non-admin user runs it, they claim to get this:

Component `RICHTX32.OCX` or one of its dependencies not correctly registered: a file is missing or invalid.

All users can read/execute this `RICHTX32.OCX` file.   Why is this happening I can't find anything about this anywhere?  Could it be a registry key permission issue?

Thanks
Scott Emick

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is download RICHX32.OCX from **[here**](https://www.ocxme.com/getfile.php?file=9&id=045a16822822426c305ea7280270a3d6) and...

**For 32-bit Windows:**

```
Copy it to c:\windows\system32
Click Windows Start icon at bottom left
Select All Programs, then Accessories
Right-click Command Prompt, then select "Run as administrator"
In the command prompt, type:  regsvr32 c:\windows\system32\RICHTX32.OCX
```

**For 64-bit Windows 7 or later:**

```
Copy it to c:\windows\syswow64
Click Windows Start icon at bottom left
Select All Programs, then Accessories
Right-click Command Prompt, then select "Run as administrator"
In the command prompt, type:  regsvr32 c:\windows\syswow64\RICHTX32.OCX
```

for more visit : [here](https://www.k6jm.com/hs-setupocx.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The real answer was...I had to go there....log onto the terminal server....copy the same files to c:\windows\syswow64 and register them manually. Now everyone is working..